# sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a remote `sh` from `Jenkins` to change a script to executable, but I take the following error:

```
[-manager_feature_kubernetes-YYLYXREUAV4NHLBACWJHV5YMQFOGHM4SS7G67ASIGYSZZGVS4VBQ] Running shell script
+ sshpass -p **** ssh'****@10.XX.XX.XXX chmod u + x /home/Script.sh '
sshpass: Failed to run command: No such file or directory
```

The logic of my script is:

```
sh "sshpass -p \" $ {passSSH} \ "ssh ${userSSH}@10.XX.XX.XXX \" chmod u + x /home/Script.sh \ ""
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this:

```
sshpass -p '$rootPassword' ssh -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' $isRoot@$Host "chmod u+x /home/$USER/Script.sh"
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write it here : my docker container did not have package `lftp` installed

a simple `apt-get install lftp` solved this issue.

Hope it will help ;)

Comment: Great! It depends on your command but it also could be the `rsync` package or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was using docker container of alpine linux in which `openssh` was missing so `sshpass` failing. After installing `openssh` package it solved.
`apk add openssh`
(so just incase if some one faces same)

Comment: This worked for me, specifically on cytopia alpine ansible.  I already had `sshpass` added but not `openssh`.

Answer (score 0):

$rootPassword,$isRoot, $Host are Jenkins string parameter

sshpass -p ""$rootPassword"" ssh $isRoot@$Host id; echo $HOME;