# Gitlab returns Permission denied (publickey,password) for digitalocean server

Tags: django, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, digital-ocean

I'm trying to implement CD for my dockerized Django application on the DigitalOcean droplet.

Here's my **`.gitlab-ci.yml`**:

```
image:
  name: docker/compose:1.29.1
  entrypoint: [""]

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

before_script:
  - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
  - export WEB_IMAGE=$IMAGE/web:web
  - export NGINX_IMAGE=$IMAGE/nginx:nginx
  - apk add --no-cache openssh-client bash
  - chmod +x ./setup_env.sh
  - bash ./setup_env.sh
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull $IMAGE/web:web || true
    - docker pull $IMAGE/web:nginx || true
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml build
    - docker push $IMAGE/web:web
    - docker push $IMAGE/nginx:nginx

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod +x ./deploy.sh
    - scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose.prod.yml root@$DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:/Pythonist.org
    - bash ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
```

I have copied my Publick key to the production server (DO droplet).
The build job is successful but the deploy stage failed with the following error:

```
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 26
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (abdul12391@gmail.com)
$ ssh-keyscan -H 'gitlab.com' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ chmod +x ./deploy.sh
$ scp  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./.env ./docker-compose.prod.yml root@$DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:/Pythonist.org
Warning: Permanently added '143.198.103.99' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
root@143.198.103.99: Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: You have to copy the ssh key to the remote server with this command : `ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub root@$DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS`. This with add your public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file

Answer (score 1):

Try the following on the digital ocean server:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

and copy the public key to authorized keys

```
nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

then change permission

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

The official process is "[How to Upload an SSH Public Key to an Existing Droplet](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/to-existing-droplet/)", but it usually involves `username`, not `root`.

While your pipeline might be executed as root (as the `Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa` message suggests), your `scp` should use a DO remote user, not the remote DO `root` account): the same account username where you have added the public key to the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

So:

```
username@$DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:/Pythonist.org
# not
root@$DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS:/Pythonist.org
```

Comment: I'm using the `root` user on server.

Comment: @AbdulRehman OK. Did you enable root access through SSH on the remote DO droplet? (as in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-enable-root-login)

Comment: yes I did, I can see `PasswordAuthentication` set to `yes` in my `sshd_config`

Comment: @AbdulRehman And restarted the sshd on the remote DO side?

Comment: yes, did restart sshd

Comment: @AbdulRehman so would a simple `ssh root@DO_PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS` work?

Comment: it requires the password to SSH using `root`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237464/discussion-between-vonc-and-abdul-rehman).

Comment: @VonC similiar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465391/deploying-using-github-actions-in-digital-ocean-docker-username-and-password-err :D